# JavaFX and jfoenix: cannot find symbol JFXHamburger

Tags: java, javafx, jfoenix

as the image shows i am not able to use the JFXHamburger class even with imported jfoenix library.
For testing i used the wildcard to import everything:

```
import com.jfoenix.*;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to use 
`import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXHamburger;`. Works now.